# bit.ly dynamic link php

Tags: php, variables, dynamic, hyperlink, bit.ly

I am trying to use bit.ly in my website. When I do this:

```
$short_url = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=myLogin&apiKey=myApiKey&longUrl=".urlencode("http://example.com")."&format=json"))->data->url;
```

It works fine.

However when I try placing the link in a variable.

```
$link = 'http://example.com';
$short_url = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=myLogin&apiKey=myApiKey&longUrl=".urlencode(**$link**)."&format=json"))->data->url;
```

It does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `"It doesn't work"` - Very ambiguous. What is happening? What should happen?

Comment: Nothing outputs. If I echo $short_url it is blank

Comment: Okay, see your question. I have formatted it, can you please verify it is perfectly same as how you have written?

Comment: First, make sure the strings passed to `file_get_contents()` match.  Then, look at (and edit in) the output of `file_get_contents()` before it's passed to `json_decode()`.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're referring too

Comment: @Praveen Yes what you edited was exactly what I want. The bottom one is what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Check what is the output of `file_get_contents()`. You can do it this way:

```
var_dump(file_get_contents("http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=myLogin&apiKey=myApiKey&longUrl=".urlencode($link)."&format=json"));
```

If there's a good output there, check and then pass it to `json_encode()`.

Comment: Yes I know it is just there to emphasize the word. It was to bold it on this site. What you have there is what I have on my site.

Comment: @user939951 I have updated the answer. Try them out and let me know.

Comment: Okay, get me the output of what's in my answer right now and update it in the question.

Comment: I really don't even know how to be honest

Comment: As I said before nothing gets outputed

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump()`?

Comment: string(64) "{ "data": [ ], "status_code": 500, "status_txt": "INVALID_URI" }"

Comment: That's the issue. See, you have a `500 Internal Server error`! It is nothing to do with your script. Try giving the URL directly on the browser and check.

Comment: As I said when I hard code the url such as http://example.com there aren't any issues however when I do $link = http://example.com nothing outputs

Comment: I figured out another solution. I found a php function

Comment: Thanks for your help I will use your answer as the correct one.